# Text overlying Text and be scalable.

Tags: html, css, text

I'm just getting back into Web Development and so I'm working on stretching those muscles again. What I wanted to achieve was a Header on top of my vertical menu with the Initials in the background and the full name in the middle of those initials. I was able to do that with the code in codepen, however it quickly becomes broken when resizing the window. I know that is due in part to the position absolute. Is there another way to achieve this effect and have it be scalable, but stay within the lines of the nav?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OPPKmq

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Scottish Arts</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
<div id="body">
<aside>

</aside>

<nav>
    <h1 id="navSA">SA<h1>
    <h1 id="sa">Socttish Arts</h1>
    <ul>
        <li><h3></h3></li>
        <li><a href=" ">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href=" ">Scottish Arts</a></li>
        <li><a href=" ">Bagpipes</a></li>
        <li><a href=" ">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>


</div>


</body>
</html>

html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

h1,h2,h3 {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#body {
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
}

aside {
    width: 25px;
    height: 100%;
    background: url("img/nhtar.gif");

    background-repeat: repeat;
    border-right: 2px #000 solid;

}

nav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 15%;
    background-color: #7E717A;
    border-right: 4px #A2969E solid;
  overflow: hidden;
}

nav #navSA {
    font-weight: bolder;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 8em;
    color: #A2969E;
}

nav #sa {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 60px;
    left: 40px;
    font-size: 2em;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px #7E717A;

}

nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

nav ul li {
    list-style: none;
    text-align: right;
}

nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #A2969E;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-family: "Verdana";
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff;
    border-bottom: 4px #7E717A solid;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
    background-color: #372E34;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Giving absolute Position to a child that does not have relative parent , will set it's position relating to BODY .
add `position:relative;` to `nav` in css , and everything will be OK ;)

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LEEwOd